# How to connect to jdbc using @Bean in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, annotations, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring MVC. I am trying to connect to jdbc with DriverManagerDataSource. I am using
@Bean annotation. I am basically trying to achieve something like this in the xml file using annotations.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jcg" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="toor" />
</bean>
```

I am using @configuration annotation in my configuration class, doing this to connect using @Bean in my configuration file.

```
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
    Properties jdbcProperties = PropertyUtils.getProperties(profile, "jdbc");
    
    DriverManagerDataSource ret = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ret.setDriverClassName(jdbcProperties.getProperty("driverClassName"));
    ret.setUsername(jdbcProperties.getProperty("username"));
    ret.setPassword(jdbcProperties.getProperty("password"));
    ret.setUrl(jdbcProperties.getProperty("url"));
    return ret;
}
```

I saw this in another stackoverflow question. Is this the correct way?
But I am getting the error.

> Properties cannot be resolved
>
> PropertyUtils cannot be resolved

I am not sure how I can import these? Also I dont understand what profile stands for here? Can you please help?

Comment: You don't have to use PropertyUtils (from Apache Commons I guess) to import properties in an Spring application. Use [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to say anything about `profile` variable and error messages look like you've not imported `PropertyUtils` class.

One of the proper way to import properties into an Spring application is to use [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) as I mentioned in the comment. Declare a bean in your configuration class like this.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

and then specify the property file name in your configuration class and place the configuration file on the classpath.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")})
public class YourConfig {...}
```

In order to use properties specified in the property file, you need to inject an [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) instance.

```
@Resource
private Environment environment;
```

Then use it to get property values.

```
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
   DriverManagerDataSource ret = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   ret.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("driverClassName"));
   ret.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("username"));
   ret.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("password"));
   ret.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("url"));
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bunti, I was able to solve this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by using this

```
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource ret = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ret.setDriverClassName("driverClassName");
    ret.setUsername("username");
    ret.setPassword("password");
    ret.setUrl("url");
    return ret;
}
```